# How to add multiple key constraints for ORM eager loading in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, orm, eager-loading

Suppose I have three relations:

```
 1. departments
        - id (primary)
        - name
 2. quotas
        - id (primary)
        - name
 3. department_quota
        - id (primary)
        - department_id (foreign)
        - quota_id (foreign)
        - number_of_seats
        - unique(department_id, quota_id)
```

Now, I want to access `number_of_seats` per `department` grouped by `quota`, again I want to access `number_of_seats` per `quota` grouped by `department`. I need to do this task using laravel ORM eager loading.

I can access all `quotas` with `departments` using :

```
\App\Quota::with('departments')->get();
```

and also the opposite thing using by:

```
\App\Department::with('quotas')->get();
```

Yes, this is a many-to-many relation.
But how can I access the `number_of_seats` as stated above ?

I need this because I am to serve the relation as `JSON` serialized data for `REST`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both models are `belongsToMany` you can add `withPivot()` to your `departments()` method.

```
public function departments(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Department')->withPivot('number_of_seats');
}
```

it will be included in the json collection and it can be reached via code with

```
foreach(Quota::with('departments')->get() as $quota){
       foreach($quota->departments as $department){
           echo $department->pivot->number_of_seats;
       }
    }
```